# How to load script based on user referer

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to load some javascript based on  user referer  Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following, it takes the referer and with an if statement load what you need based on it!

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match("/site1.com/",$referrer)) {
      header('Location: http://www.customercare.com/page-site1.html');
} elseif (preg_match("/site2.com/",$referrer)) {
      header('Location: http://www.customercare.com/page-site2.html');
} else {
      header('Location: http://www.customercare.com/home-page.html');
};
```